# ¿Cómo combinar 2 resultados y que se exporte en formato CSV? Python

Tags: python, jupyter

Tengo este resultado:

```
print(X_train_res):

[[ 1.          1.          1.          1.         34.59838     1.
   2.          2.          2.424569    1.          2.        ]
 [ 3.          2.          1.          1.         41.63        2.
   2.          3.         15.375       0.          1.        ]
 [ 1.          1.          1.          1.         47.5         1.
   2.          1.          2.1         1.          2.        ]
 [ 1.          2.          1.          1.         51.35        1.
   2.          3.         12.9         0.          1.        ]
 [ 1.          1.          1.          1.         53.1         1.
   2.          2.          9.5         1.          2.        ]
 [ 1.          2.          2.          1.         41.58        2.
   1.          1.         11.05        0.          2.        ]
 [ 1.          1.          1.          2.         34.8         1.
   2.          2.          6.85        1.          2.        ]] 

print(y_train_res):

[1 0 1 0 0 0 1]
```

---

Este es mi código en formato CSV:

```
datos = (X_train_res)

csvsalida = open('Resultado_Smote1.csv', 'w', newline='')

salida = csv.writer(csvsalida)

salida.writerow(['Campo1', 'Campo2', 'Campo3', 'Campo4', 'Campo5', 
'Campo6', 'Campo7','Campo8', 'Campo9', 'Campo10', 'Campo11'])

salida.writerows(datos)

del salida

csvsalida.close()
```

---

Lo que deseó hacer es agregarla la columna de `y_train_res(1 columnas)` en `X_train_res(11 columnas)` y obtener 12 columnas y escribirlo en un csv

Answer (score 0):

Por el formato del `print` intuyo que ambos resultados son arrays de NumPy, por lo que voy a partir desde este punto para reproducir tu código:

```
import numpy as np



X_train_res = np.array([[1, 1, 1, 1, 34.59838, 1, 2, 2, 2.424569, 1, 2],
                        [3, 2, 1, 1, 41.63, 2, 2, 3, 15.375, 0, 1,],
                        [1, 1, 1, 1, 47.5, 1, 2, 1, 2.1,1,2],
                        [1, 2, 1, 1, 51.35, 1, 2, 3, 12.9, 0,1],
                        [1, 1, 1, 1, 53.1, 1, 2, 2, 9.5, 1, 2],
                        [1, 2, 2, 1, 41.58, 2, 1, 1, 11.05, 0, 2],
                        [1, 1, 1, 2, 34.8, 1, 2, 2, 6.85, 1, 2 ],
                        ])

y_train_res = np.array([1, 0, 1, 0, 0, 0, 1])
```

Para crear tu csv añadiendo `y_train_res` como la duodécima columna tienes varias posibilidades, entre ellas se me ocurre:

### Usar `numpy.savetxt`

Si bien es un tanto limitado para esto es suficiente y bastante simple, el problema es que hay que crear una copia del array para lo que podemos usar `numpy.column_stack` para añadir la columna, aunque con el tamaño de arrays que muestras esto no es muy relevante:

```
import numpy as np



header = ['Campo1', 'Campo2', 'Campo3', 'Campo4', 'Campo5', 'Campo6',
          'Campo7', 'Campo8', 'Campo9', 'Campo10', 'Campo11', "Campo12"]

np.savetxt("Resultado_Smote1.csv",
           np.column_stack((X_train_res, y_train_res)),
           fmt="%.6f", # Decimales a mostrar
           header=",".join(header),
           delimiter=',',
           newline='\n',
           encoding="UTF-8",
           comments=""
           )
```

### Usar el módulo csv de la biblioteca estándar

Esta es la opción que muestras en tu código, para agregar la columna puedes hacer uso de `zip` para iterar a la par sobre ambos arrays o usar `np.column_stack` como antes:

```
import csv



header = ['Campo1', 'Campo2', 'Campo3', 'Campo4', 'Campo5', 'Campo6',
          'Campo7', 'Campo8', 'Campo9', 'Campo10', 'Campo11', "Campo12"]

with open('Resultado_Smote1.csv', 'w', newline='') as csv_salida:
    writer = csv.writer(csv_salida)
    writer.writerow(header)
    writer.writerows(np.append(x, y) for x, y in zip(X_train_res, y_train_res))
    # writer.writerows(np.column_stack((X_train_res, y_train_res))
```

Si se quiere especificar el número de decimales podemos usar formateo de cadenas:

```
writer.writerows((f"{n:.6f}" for n in np.append(x, y))
    for x, y in zip(X_train_res, y_train_res)
    )
```

ó:

```
writer.writerows((f"{n:.6f}" for n in row) 
    for row in np.column_stack((X_train_res, y_train_res))
    )
```

### "Manualmente" sin usar ningún módulo:

```
header = ['Campo1', 'Campo2', 'Campo3', 'Campo4', 'Campo5', 'Campo6',
          'Campo7', 'Campo8', 'Campo9', 'Campo10', 'Campo11', "Campo12"]


with open ("Resultado_Smote1.csv", "w") as csv_file:
    csv_file.write(",".join(header) + "\n")
    for x, y in zip(X_train_res, y_train_res):
        csv_file.write(",".join(f"{n:.6f}" for n in x))
        csv_file.write(f",{y:.6f}\n")
```

Se usa formateo de literales de cadena disponible en Python >= 3.6 para ajustar el número de decimales. Se puede substituir `str.format` pero la eficiencia es considerablemente inferior.

### Usar Pandas

Posiblemente crear un `DataFrame` solo para generar el csv sea demasiado, no obstante es muy simple y si previamente vamos a operar con la tabla para terminal en última instancia generando un csv es posiblemente la mejor opción, mantenemos la eficiencia de NumPy y `pandas.to_csv` es mucho más potente y orientado realmente a generar `.csv` que `numpy.savetxt`:

```
import pandas as pd



header = ['Campo1', 'Campo2', 'Campo3', 'Campo4', 'Campo5', 'Campo6',
          'Campo7', 'Campo8', 'Campo9', 'Campo10', 'Campo11']

df = pd.DataFrame(X_train_res, columns=header)
df["Campo12"] = y_train_res
df.to_csv("Resultado_Smote1.csv", sep=",", index=False, float_format="%.6f")
```